# Gradle compile and jar a subset of java classes

Tags: gradle

I want to compile (with a different targetCompatibility and sourceCompatibility) and jar a small subset of my whole main/src/java folder.

So I have e.g.

```
main/src/java/com/interface/A.java
main/src/java/com/interface/B.java
main/src/java/com/logic/C.java
```

I want to compile A and B to a jar "projectname_projectversion_interface.jar" and using a different compiler version.

Is this possible? How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend to use a separate source set:

```
apply plugin: "java"

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            exclude "com/interface/A.java"
            exclude "com/interface/B.java"
        }
    }
    api {
        java {
            srcDir "src/main/java"
            include "com/interface/A.java"
            include "com/interface/B.java"
        }
    }
}
```

If `main` depends on `api`, add something like:

```
sourceSets.main.compileClasspath += sourceSets.api.output
```

Source/target compatibility can be adjusted on the compile task level:

```
compileApiJava {
    sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
    targetCompatibility = "1.7"
}
```

To use a compiler other than that belonging to the JDK that Gradle itself is run with, you'll have to set a compiler executable:

```
compileApiJava {
    options.fork = true
    options.forkOptions.executable = "/path/to/compiler/executable"
}
```

This may slow down the build to some extent.

For further API details, check out the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html).

Comment: I added this: 

task jarApi(type: Jar) {
   dependsOn compileApiJava
   from sourceSets.api.output
   classifier = 'api'
}

task sourcesApiJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: apiClasses) {
   classifier = 'api-sources'
   from sourceSets.api.allSource
}

Comment: Right, I forgot that a Jar task isn't automatically added for each source set.